# Timestamp : from UNIX to MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

On one side, I have a MySQL DB where there is table that has a timestamp field. According to MySQL doc, this MySQL TIMESTAMP is similar to DATETIME (with different bounds). As far as I know, the required form is : "Y-m-d H:i:s".

An extract from the DB :

```
date_heure TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

On the other side, I have a mobile app which sends data to the DB. The time is very important, so among this data (sent using JSON) there is a timestamp field. This timestamp is UNIX-like, in milliseconds.

As you guessed, my purpose is to insert the received timestamp in the database.

To do so, on server-side, I wrote the following PHP code :

```
$timestamp = $json_decode['t']; //get the UNIX timestamp from the JSON data
$sec_timestamp = $timestamp/1000; //in order to have seconds, not milliseconds
$mysql_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sec_timestamp); //converting UNIX timestamp into MySQL timestamp.
```

However, in the DB, the timestamp field still has the following form, for every row : `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

There is no problem on the app side, the UNIX timestamp (in milliseconds) is properly sent via JSON.

Hence, what can I do to insert this into the DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [built-in function `FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) in MySQL, use it:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (date_heure, ...) values (FROM_UNIXTIME(1470762668), ...)
```